# How to add a sub menu button in Magento 2 Admin Product Panel?

Tags: magento2, product, admin

How do I add this sub menu button?

The button when clicked basically shows a table, that's about it for now. 
I'm quite new to magento and it would help if you can explain at least a little bit.

How to get to the button

[image: how to get this button?]

What it can look like after clicking the button. For now, just the table would suffice. (ignore the table headings at the moment since I'm just trying it out on the Luma theme.)

[image: what the table can look like]

Comment: Could you reconfirm what you want to achieve ? Do you want to add a menu item or do you want to add a sub menu item in the admin panel ?

Comment: A submenu item in the admin panel. Thanks, ill make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

This menus or submenus are the entry point of the respective module. If you want to add just submenu then update menu.xml file of respective module (*note: Don't mess with core modules." please create your own module"*) 
and this menu and submenus are defined in the menu.xml file located at "Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml"

/*****************menu.xml********************/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
            <!--for menu-->
        <add id="Cloudways_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
             title="Cloudways Admin Menu"
             module="Cloudways_Adminmenu"
             sortOrder="20"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
        />
           <!--for submenu-->
        <add id="Cloudways_Adminmenu::second_level_demo"
             title="Sub Menu"
             module="Cloudways_Adminmenu"
             sortOrder="1"
             action="menuitem/index/index"
             parent="Cloudways_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
        />
    </menu>
</config>
```

ok,thats it,
it may help you

Comment: Thanks! Made the panel already. But how do i set the table (or make page) once the button is clicked?

Comment: in your module, there is a 'block/adminhtml/modulename/edit/grid' folder.this folder contains all files of that table. if you not created it so just follow steps to create 'grid' at admin side